# Get the real mouse location on a canvas with double context

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, code-injection

I have been asked to get the mouse coordinates in a game made in html5 with canvas.
As a first test, try reading the mouse position with the function below. But this function only reads the mouse position taking into account the dimensions of the canvas.

What happens is that the game has a larger stage than the canvas and this function does not show me the real location of the character on the stage.

I was doing a search and noticed that "**behind**" the canvas exists on a map (.png) with pixel dimensions already established. The canvas works like the camera to see a portion of the map.

Will it be possible to adapt my function to read the dimensions of the map and then locate the actual coordinates of the player?

```
        var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
            var cRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

            var scaleX = canvas.width / cRect.width;
            var scaleY = canvas.height / cRect.height;

            var canvasX = Math.round((e.clientX - cRect.left) * scaleX);
            var canvasY = Math.round((e.clientY - cRect.top) * scaleY);

            console.log("X: "+canvasX+", Y: "+canvasY);
        });
```

This function will only give me the position of the mouse based on the size of the canvas but the map is larger, I leave here an explanatory image.

[image]

I hope you have understood me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: save yourself some time and pain and just use a game engine https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Comment: Is anything exposing the position of that background?

Comment: @Kaiido, there are another example that I've found: https://dragonbound.net 
As you can see, it uses a larger background than the canvas. Will there be the possibility of obtaining the exact location of the players?

Comment: If hey do expose the current coordinates of the camera based on the world, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: do you have an example about this?

Comment: Well if you know the camera is at world's coords 300, 400, then when your mouse is over camera's coords 20, 50, your mouse is at world's coords 320, 450.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### World <=> View

To establish the vernacular, the terms used are

- **World**: the coordinate system (in pixels) of world / playfield / (red box).
- **View**: The coordinate system (in canvas pixels) of canvas / camera / (blue box).

As pointed out in the comments. You need the view origin. That is the coordinates that the top left of the canvas in world space.

You also need to know the view scale. That is the size of the canvas in relationship to the world.

#### Required information

```
const world = {width: 2048, height: 1024}; // Red box in pixels
const view = {  // blue box
    origin: {x: 500, y: 20},      // in world scale (pixels on world)
    scale: {width: 1, height: 1}, // scale of pixels (from view to world)
}
```

Without this information you **can not** do the conversion. It must exist as it is required to render world content to the canvas.

**Note** that if the scales are `1` they may only be inferred in the canvas rendering system. If you can not find a scale then use `1`.

**Note** This answer assumes there is no rotation of the view.

### View => World

The following function will convert from view coordinates to world coordinates.

```
function viewToWorld(x, y) { // x,y pixel coordinates on canvas
    return {
        x: x * view.scale.width + view.origin.x,
        y: y * view.scale.height + view.origin.y
    };     // return x,y pixel coordinates in world
}
```

To use in a mouse event where the client is the canvas

```
function mouseEvent(event) {
    // get world (red box) coords 
    const worldCoord = viewToWorld(event.clientX, event.clientY);

    // normalize
    worldCoord.x /= world.width;
    worldCoord.y /= world.height;
}
```

### World => View

You can reverse the conversion. That is move from world coordinates to view coordinates with the following functions.

```
function normalWorldToView(x, y) { // x,y normalized world coordinates
    return {
        x: (x * world.width - view.origin.x) / view.scale.width,
        y: (y * world.height - view.origin.y) / view.scale.height
    };     // return x,y pixel on canvas (view)
}
```

and in pixels

```
function worldToView(x, y) { // x,y world coordinates in pixels
    return {
        x: (x - view.origin.x) / view.scale.width,
        y: (y - view.origin.y) / view.scale.height
    };     // return x,y pixel on canvas (view)
}
```

Comment: This information has been very useful to me, one last question. I have checked in the game source and when the camera moves to a certain location, the "transform" property returns values of type (-575px, -30px). I know this div moves the camera because I manipulated the values and the camera moves to a specific location.
https://i.ibb.co/SPxftbM/camara.png How can I interpret this to apply your solution?

Comment: @Kokox The values `-575, -30` are the inverted origin coordinates (move the world left and up so that the top left of the view (canvas) is over the world coords 575, 30). Using answers code the origin would be `view.origin.x = 575` and `view.origin.y = 30`

Comment: therefore, the value must be previously multiplied by -1